# Passing 2 models to a view possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a view that must render two reports.

My action:

```
public ActionResult TradeUKKPIShowData(SundaysInMonthViewModel model) //show actual data in the view
{
  var tradesmenReportData = _reportingService.GetTradeUKKPITradesmen(model.SelectedSunday);
  var jobSortedReportData = _reportingService.GetTradeUKKPIJobSorted(model.SelectedSunday);
  ViewBag.jobSortedReportDate = model.SelectedSunday;
  ViewBag.addJobSortedModel = jobSortedReportData;
  return View(tradesmenReportData);
}
```

My first problem is with the first two lines of the action above. What must I pass here?
The compile errors I get for those lines:

'TradeUK.Services.IReportingService.GetTradeUKKPITradesmen(TradeUK.Entities.Reporting.KPIResults)' has some invalid arguments

All the stored procedure for the report needs is the date/sunday that was selected

My SundaysInMonthViewModel:

```
 namespace TradeUK.Admin.Web.ViewModels
 {
    public class SundaysInMonthViewModel
    {
       public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllSundays { set; get; }
       public string SelectedSunday { set; get; }
    }
 }
```

Here IReportingServices.cs:

```
IEnumerable<KPIResults> GetTradeUKKPITradesmen(DateTime date);
IEnumerable<KPIResults> GetTradeUKKPIJobSorted(DateTime date);
```

and the actual methods for above:

```
 public IEnumerable<KPIResults> GetTradeUKKPITradesmen(DateTime date)
 {
 }


 public IEnumerable<KPIResults> GetTradeUKKPIJobSorted(DateTime date)
 {
 }
```

KPIResults:

```
namespace TradeUK.Entities.Reporting
{
 public class KPIResults
  {
   public virtual string Title { get; set; }
   public virtual int Total { get; set; }
   public virtual int Week6 { get; set; }
   public virtual int Week5 { get; set; }
   public virtual int Week4 { get; set; }
   public virtual int Week3 { get; set; }
   public virtual int Week2 { get; set; }
   public virtual int Week1 { get; set; }
  }
 }
```

The other issue is on the return(View(tradesmenReportData,jobSortedReportData)
Can I do this? In the actual view I have to foreach loops to show the to sets of report data.

Please help?
Thanks

Comment: What is the definition of `IReportingService.GetTradeUKKPITradesmen` and what is the type of `model.SelectedSunday`? Somehow I don't think that the latter is `TradeUK.Entities.Reporting.KPIResults`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass first model normally and second in `ViewBag` and then

```
@model YourFirstModelClass

@{
    YourSecondModelClass model2 = ViewBag.YourSecondModel;
}
```

And and with it you have effect which you want.

So when you do not use Razor you can add primary strongly typed model like this:

```
<%@ Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<PrimaryModelClass>" %>
```

and second in ViewData similary to ViewBag

Comment: I added my view code in OP is this correct? I am still in the learning process and dont know how quite yet. I am not using razor. Thanks

Comment: I use one model for both reports they have the same make up so in my case it will be SundaysInMonthViewModel? thanks

Comment: sorry I have there: System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<TradeUK.Entities.Reporting.KPIResults>> please see OP thanks

Comment: So if `_reportingService.GetTradeUKKPITradesmen(model.SelectedSunday)` is `IEnumerable<TradeUK.Entities.Reporting.KPIResults>` type it should work fine. You have an error?

Comment: it is not, model.SelectedSunday belong to model SundaysInMonthViewModel. KPIResults is class for the data/output in the report...yikes

Comment: I do not understand you at all. So I can not help you sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your "second issue":

No, you can't do that, there's only one `Model` in `ViewData`. You should create separate viewmodel for this case (or use something like `Tuple`).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second issue, you can create one modelView class with property of both tables' column.  From this model class you can view the data in view page and save the data in the particular tables.

Answer (score -1):

I found this link on the web which may do it for you.

https://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/passing-multiple-models-to-a-view-in-an-asp-net-mvc-5-0-application

Edit :-

The page I have linked to suggests passing a List of Objects to the View, with the list being made up od different Models, here is the example.

```
public ActionResult Index()
   {
         List<object> model = new List<object>();
         model.Add(ctx.ProductCategories.ToList());
         model.Add(ctx.Products.ToList());

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Then in the View you can break the List down to individual models again, here is the example the author gives :-

```
@model IEnumerable<object>

@{

    List<PassingMultipleModelsToAView.ProductCategory> lstPCategory = Model.ToList()[0] as List<PassingMultipleModelsToAView.ProductCategory>;

    List<PassingMultipleModelsToAView.Product> lstProduct = Model.ToList()[1] as List<PassingMultipleModelsToAView.Product>;
}

<h3>Categories</h3>

<ul>
    @foreach (var item in lstPCategory)
    {    
        <li>@item.Name</li>
    }
</ul>

<hr />

<h3>Products</h3>

<ul>
    @foreach (var item in lstProduct)
    {
        <li>@item.Name-@item.Color</li>
    }
</ul>
```